# Android Cursor move to position based on ID

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

Can we move a `cursor` in `Android` to a certain position based on `ID`?

The `moveToPosition()` uses the position of type `int` to move the `cursor`. I need to move the `cursor` to a record based on the stored `ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry. `Cursor` has no form of internal query engine to find positions based on particular cell values ("find me the position in which cell whose name is `_id` has the value of 123").

Comment: I see. Thanks. I am stuck at the following problem which involves the cursor adapter. Any input on this would be great as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124976/searchview-suggestions-adapter-checkbox?noredirect=1#comment91207752_52124976